# Force Quit Windows Folder on GoToMyPC — entire interface now missing

Tags: mac, keyboard, windows, remote-desktop, pc

I am logged into my work PC through GoToMyPC on my Mac laptop (running Monterey 12.6). On the windows desktop, a folder saved to my desktop froze, so I ended it with task manager. I think I ended “windows.exe” because now all icons, the bar at the bottom, the start button, and just about everything else is missing and inaccessible. A fix I read online begins with typing control/alt/delete to bring up task manager. No combination seems to work on my Mac laptop. I’ve found at least 5 suggested control, alt, delete variations to use on my Mac keyboard — none work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It will be in the app's menu bar somewhere. Sending controls of this type always needs to be a 'special' command, you can't just press the keys. BTW, if you want to get straight to Task Manager on Win it's quicker to send Ctrl/Shift/Esc, if the menu has that too.